# Monitoring a flag status for a few seconds

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, monitoring

I wanted to monitor the status of a flag once it is set when a switch is pressed for about 5 seconds. Once the switch is pressed  the flag is set flase, once pressed I want to keep checking for 5 more seconds if switch is pressed. If it is not, I need to check again for switch pressed. If pressed, again monitor it for 5 more seconds. If pressed for 5 seconds call another function, function1()

```
def switch():
     while(flag == True):
         switch=GPIO.input(1)
         if (switch==0):
            time.sleep(5)
            function1()
            Active = False
            function2()
```

The way I have written it above is that I just sleep it for 5 seconds, and then check after 5 seconds, which is not what I want. Can anyone please tell me how to perform the logic I mentioned above ?

**EDIT:**  I just need to know if the switch continues to remain pressed for 5 seconds once it is pressed. If it is depressed during that 5 seconds, then I again need to check if switch is pressed again, then again continue for 5 seconds, until the switch remians pressed for 5 seconds

Comment: Are asking how to execute one method if the switch is held for 5 seconds and another if it is held for 10 seconds total?

Comment: Is there any sort of event that fires continuously while it is held? I guess the main issue here isn't whether you can measure the time that's passed (you can, and it's simple, and I'll show you), but how switch is implemented and firing events. For example: is there an event that fires when the user releases the switch?

Comment: @furkle There is a flag I am monitoring in the beginning of the function. That flag is set true from another function. Once that flag is raised and this function which is running as a thread reads that flag, it starts checking for the switch status. Once the switch logic I explained above is satisfied I set the flag to false at the end of this function, and call another function. Is it possible to just use one function (function1) to write this logic, as opposed to two functions as you have written below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, one way I think you could do this is to use a timer. This is assuming that you also get an event when the user releases the switch. With the time library imported:

```
switch_flag = False
start_time = 0
end_time = 0

def switch():
    global switch_flag, start_time
    switch_flag = True
    start_time = time.time()

def unswitch():
    global switch_flag, start_time, end_time
    switch_flag = False
    end_time = time.time()
    if end_time - start_time > 5:
        print("5 seconds elapsed!")
```

There are some platform/granularity concerns with the python timers, but if we're talking 5 seconds I doubt it'll be an issue.

Comment: @bobdxcool Right, what I'm asking is twofold - firstly, does switch() only fire once when the switch is pressed? And two, how is it determined when the switch is released?

Comment: actually the switch is connected to a GPIO pin of a microcontroller. So, the variable assigned to the switch gets a high or low. I have edited my original code. The variable, switch gets updated to 0 if switch is pressed and to 1 if switch is not pressed

Comment: @bobdxcool Hm, sorry for the interrogation - so what happens when the switch gets lifted? Is all that happens in that case just that the value you can read from the microcontroller 0 instead of 1? Mostly I'm just curious because you seem to be able to tell perfectly when the switch has been pressed, but not when it's unpressed?

Comment: the switch variable (not switchflag which is changed in the code posted) in the code I have posted goes to 1 when switch is unpressed.What I need to do is once flag is set True in my code switch() function is called, where if switch is pressed, switch variable==0. Now once switch is pressed, I need to start checking if switch is pressed for 5 more seconds. If it is pressed for 5 more seconds, I call another function asnd set flag = False, else if switch is released within this 5 seconds(switch==1), then I need to go back to start of switch() function and again check if switch is presse

Comment: @bobdxcool Okay, so you need to execute an action is the switch is held down for five seconds exactly on five seconds, not "when the switch is undepressed if it had been held for >=5s." That makes more sense - I think you're going to need a separate thread timer for that. One sec.

Comment: thats right. I just need to know if the switch continues to remain pressed for 5 seconds once it is pressed. If it is depressed during that 5 seconds, then I again need to check if switch is pressed again, then again continue for 5 seconds, until the switch remians pressed for 5 seconds

Comment: @bobdxcool I'll see if I can work up a solution for that. Might not be immediately, though.

Comment: were you able to find a method to do this ?